# Create PDF with name instead of creating the file in drive and renaming

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filenames, export-to-pdf

Currently my script saves the *PDF* with the name `export.pdf` and then renames it to the value I have in one of the cells of my spreadsheet, the problem with that is that my website's *API* ends up taking the file when it is created and all are collected like `export.pdf` instead of the name I really need.

Is there an option to create the *PDF* with the correct name instead of renaming it?

[image]

```
    //Create PDF
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/' +
      'IDSPREADSHEETIDSPREADSHEETIDSPREADSHEET' +
        '/export?format=pdf' +
          '&size=0' +
            '&portrait=true' +
              '&fitw=true' + 
                '&top_margin=0' +            
                  '&bottom_margin=0' +         
                    '&left_margin=0' +        
                      '&right_margin=0' +     
                        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
                          '&pagenum=false' +
                            '&gridlines=false' +
                              '&fzr=FALSE' +
                                '&gid=' +
                                  'IDPAGEIDPAGEIDPAGEIDPAGE';
    
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
    var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();
    
    //...get token and Blob (do not create the file);
    
    var fileName = ss.getSheetByName("Gerais").getRange("H2").getValue();
    
    //Access or create the 'Squads' folder;
    var folder;
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads");
    if(folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    }else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Squads");
    }
    
    //Remove duplicate file with the same name;
    var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    if(existing.hasNext()) {
      var duplicate = existing.next();
      if (duplicate.getOwner().getEmail() == Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
        var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
        var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
          method: 'delete',
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
        });
        var status = dres.getResponseCode();
        if (status >=400) {
          
        } else if (status == 204) {
          folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);
        }
      }
    } else {
      folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Setting file name after creating file

  ```
  folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);
  ```

#### Solution:

- [Set the blob name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob?#setName(String)) before creating file:

  ```
  folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(fileName));
  ```