# Google script saving from excel to PDF not updating date and sum in PDF but ok in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf

Thanks in advance for any insights on the below!

I have written a script that saves a google sheet to PDF in google drive, then emails the PDF as an attachment via Gmail.

The script was running fine until the other day when I started having issues with how the file was saved.
To set the file name I have the below:

```
var date = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-1));
var reportDate = yesterday.toLocaleDateString('en-AU', {dateStyle: 'long'});
var fileName = `Report ${reportDate}`;

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('*location ID*');
var Blob = Report.getParent().getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

folder.createFile(Blob).setName(fileName);
```

The report date is stuck on 23 March and won't update the PDF name. What is also throwing me is that I have the email heading as `Report ${reportDate}` and the correct date is showing.

In the report I also have columns A:E added together. Column A:C is from one tab in the workbook, column D is from another 2nd tab and column E is from a 3rd tab. The saved PDF version is only totalling the saved columns from A:C even though there is data in column D and E and the total in the google sheet report is summing all of the columns.

The issues seem to be arising with the PDF actions.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas how I can troubleshoot these.

Thank you!

I've tried clearing the script and pasting it back in. I'm a bit stuck so not much else.

Comment: It has methods here: var Blob = Report.getParent().getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
let yesterday = date;
```

Instead of this:

```
var yesterday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-1));
```

Report is undefined so the script is not reproducible

Comment: Hello! Thank you, I just tried the suggestion and unfortunately the file is still saving as March 23.

Comment: Currently Report is undefined

Comment: thank you, sorry I'm confused. The "report" isn't a variable, it's just used in the file name: var fileName = ` Report ${reportDate} `; I tried to logger.log the fileName and it comes up with the correct info; Report 30 March 2023 but it won't save the right name in folder.createFile(Blob).setName(fileName); Sorry I'm a new to all this and appreciate your help

Comment: I found a solution: folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(fileName)); setting the blob name before creating the file. This seems to have worked for now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Create PDF with name instead of creating the file in drive and renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067641/create-pdf-with-name-instead-of-creating-the-file-in-drive-and-renaming)

folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(fileName)); setting the blob name before creating the file

Comment: Please avoid make only link answers, since if the link is dead, the answer will be futile